# Warning: unable to determine the label for the provided `value`

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

Sometimes i see console warning:

```
unable to determine the label for the provided `value`. Nothing to display in the text field. This usually happens when setting an initial `value` before any items are returned from the `dataProvider` callback. Consider setting `selectedItem` instead of `value`
```

And label in combobox is cleared. But value selected correctly.

What exactly does this warning mean?
Thanks!

Vaadin 23.2.2 production mode

Comment: The warning is pretty clear. You call setValue somewhere before the data has loaded. And you should use selectItem instead

Comment: Simon, i directly not call setValue in combobox component. First i call setItems(), after binder.bindInstanceFields(this) and binder.readBean(bean). **selectItem** is method is method in combobox component?

Comment: Any custom combobox label generator or a failing #toString() impl of the bean? What are the items in the combobox?

Comment: Yes, i use custom label generator. This is a class method